# Samsung NP530U3C broken startup

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

I've got this Ultrabook with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and working perfectly fine till yesterday. The exact model code is: NP530U3C-AB2AR. It's out of warranty already.

Any hints on fixing the following I will greatly appreciate. Even if I take it to Samsung service I would like to have an idea of what we're talking about (because some times they don't).

Today I switch it on and it shows the following behavior repeatedly and with no modifications what so ever. In short I get to see only two screens.

In detail:

1. Starts (power and HDD blue status-lights on/blinking) and shows [Phoenix boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wodCG.jpg).
2. Makes a little power-off sound. The screen and the blue lights shut down: it reboots. This is something it always does at the first turn-on.
3. Same as point 1: Phoenix boot screen and front blue status lights on.
4. Goes straight to [Boot Menu / App Menu screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INByw.jpg). Both screens are empty, no options available. So there's nothing to do but to press TAB and ESC.
5. If TAB is hit it switches between empty Boot and App Menues. If ESC is hit the cycle starts from point 3.

I don't think there was a software/hardware/firmware modification at all, which may have caused the issue to appear. It was a clean shutdown yesterday and a bricked startup today.

What I've already tried and didn't work:

1. Removed battery (think it's called CMOS BIOS restart or something).
2. Changed memory. I've used another computer's RAM and nothing changed.
3. Disconnected HDD (I don't have a spare HDD so I haven't tried with another *connected* HDD).
4. Phoenix screen options: F2 and F4 have don't do nothing. I've also tried different other keys/key combinations just in case. I doesn't respond to them.
5. Boot with USB (bootable Windows and Ubuntu) and external DVD. It reads them (USB and DVD blinked) but it's like if they weren't connected.

Comment: Did you drop it recently? Sounds like it's broken. No boot options sounds like you've damaged the HDD, which can happen in a drop. It may/may not be bootable from USB. If the Phoenix screen / Boot Menu lets you boot from USB then I'd expect that to work, and not working could indicate motherboard problems rather than HDD problems (also can break when dropped). I'd recommend testing the HDD in a different computer, and copy off any essential data at the same time, then investigating your home and contents accidental damage insurance policy.

Comment: thanks! No, it wasn't dropped. And I don't have such an insurance policy. but I'll take your advice and check the HDD on another PC. best regards!